# error while including monk file in express.js

Tags: node.js, npm, monk

While including monk in file `app.js`, I get an error:

```
var monk = require('monk');

npm ERR! application-name@0.0.1 start: `node ./bin/www`

npm ERR! Exit status 8

npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the application-name@0.0.1 start script.

npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the application-name package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.

npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www

npm ERR! You can get their info via:

npm ERR!     npm owner ls application-name
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\n
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"

npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Acer\nodetest2
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29

npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Acer\nodetest2\npm-debug.log
```

Please help and thank you in advance. And would someone would suggest any IDE that can be used for node.js? One which shows perfect error description, as in where the errors are?

Comment: Do you have `monk` installed?

Comment: @RodrigoMedeiros , thanks .i had installed monk .but it was not working still, later i installed monk again and again it worked . Is there any IDE which can be used for node.js implementation , that  can show the proper error description .